# How can I configure Postfix to send all email through my Gmail account?

Tags: 12.04, php, mail, postfix

I'm trying to send an email through Google from my localhost.
(via PHP5.3)

But Google keeps on blocking my requests.

I tried to follow the solutions given to a few similar questions, but for some reason they do not work.

I followed these instructions to configure it - http://www.dnsexit.com/support/mailrelay/postfix.html

Now for the config data:

- my main.cf file looks like that:

> relayhost = [smtp.gmail.com]:587
>   smtp_fallback_relay = [relay.google.com]
>   smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
>   smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
>   smtp_sasl_security_options =

- my sasl_passwd looks like that:

> [smtp.gmail.com]:587    mygmailuser@gmail.com:password

- and that is how the mail.log rows look like:

> Dec 14 10:24:50 COMP-NAME postfix/pickup[5185]: 1C3987E0EDD: uid=33 from=
>
> Dec 14 10:24:50 COMP-NAME postfix/cleanup[5499]: 1C3987E0EDD: message-id=<20121214082450.1C3987E0EDD@COMP-NAME.localdomain>
>
> Dec 14 10:24:50 COMP-NAME postfix/qmgr[5186]: 1C3987E0EDD: from=, size=483, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
>
> Dec 14 10:24:50 COMP-NAME postfix/smtp[5501]: 1C3987E0EDD: to=, relay=smtp.gmail.com[173.194.70.109]:587, delay=0.61, delays=0.19/0/0.32/0.1, dsn=5.7.0, status=bounced (host smtp.gmail.com[173.194.70.109] said: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. w3sm8024250eel.17 (in reply to MAIL FROM command))
>
> Dec 14 10:24:50 COMP-NAME postfix/cleanup[5499]: C20677E0EDE: message-id=<20121214082450.C20677E0EDE@COMP-NAME.localdomain>
>
> Dec 14 10:24:50 COMP-NAME postfix/bounce[5502]: 1C3987E0EDD: sender non-delivery notification: C20677E0EDE
>
> Dec 14 10:24:50 COMP-NAME postfix/qmgr[5186]: C20677E0EDE: from=<>, size=2532, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
>
> Dec 14 10:24:50 COMP-NAME postfix/qmgr[5186]: 1C3987E0EDD: removed

Comment: my guess is that it is somehow related to
`Dec 14 10:24:50 COMP-NAME postfix/qmgr[5186]: 1C3987E0EDD: from=<www-data@COMP-NAME.localdomain>, size=483, nrcpt=1 (queue active)`

how do I change the 'from'? to a legal one?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to enable TLS in Postfix's SMTP client, since Google requires it. This is indicated by them in the message "Must issue a STARTTLS command".

In `/etc/postfix/main.cf`, you want something like this:

```
smtp_tls_policy_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/tls_policy
```

and then in `/etc/postfix/tls_policy`:

```
[smtp.gmail.com]:587 encrypt
```

The left hand side in `tls_policy` must appear exactly the same as your `relayhost` entry in `main.cf`.

Remember to run `postmap` on `/etc/postfix/tls_policy` after creating or changing it as required.

You can find more details in [Postfix's TLS documentation](http://www.postfix.org/TLS_README.html#client_tls).

Comment: PS. You may also have a sender address problem, but currently you're not getting that far. You'll need to fix the STARTTLS issue before you'll find out.

Answer (score 1):

This [very simple tutorial](https://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDwQFjAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Frtcamp.com%2Ftutorials%2Flinux%2Fubuntu-postfix-gmail-smtp%2F&ei=qGZWU9WwNeOv7Qac44HwDA&usg=AFQjCNHMrfOZVxSP3bxbQxx_RiWQnRE1uQ&sig2=pjLq8D7y5Mn2RruEH3TN9A) helped me a lot to do it.

It gives quite the same info but it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the [Ubuntu GmailPostfixFetchmail Community Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GmailPostfixFetchmail)