# How to relay gmail using postfix?

Tags: php, lamp, postfix

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I configure Postfix to send all email through my Gmail account?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/228938/how-can-i-configure-postfix-to-send-all-email-through-my-gmail-account)

I want to test php mail function from my ubuntu desktop. I heard that postfix can do this. But I don't know how to configure postfix to to send email via gmail account.